# Running out of memory with pyspark only when looping

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm running a local spark job that processes some log files. I make several passes for processing as logs from each month need to be processed separately. Everything works nicely when just doing processing  one month at a time. Even 3-4 in a loop manage to finish. But beyond that I get out of memory errors:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f4e506c7000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f4e29ee7000, 12288, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
12288 bytes for committing reserved memory.
./runspark.sh: line 1:  6222 Aborted                 (core dumped)
```

I'm running the job with:

```
spark-submit --driver-memory=12g run.py
```

Where `run.py` is something like:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

def do(sc, i):
    rdd = sc.binaryFiles("cache/{}".format(i))
    rdd1 = rdd.filter(...).map(...)
    rdd2 = rdd.filter(...).map(...)
    rdd1.persist()
    rdd2.persist()
    ...
    <processing>
    ...
    rdd1.unpersist()
    rdd2.unpersist()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    conf = SparkConf.setMaster("local[*]")
    sc = SparkContext(conf)
    for i in range(12):
        do(sc, i)
```

Keeping an eye on the spark webUI I do not see anything taking up memory on the storage tab (longer than for one loop). But looking at `htop` the memory usage keeps growing. Considering I'm unpersisting the RDDs that might take up memory I'm at a loss as to what is eating up all the memory. Running spark-1.5.2.